# Как при запуске сервера, запустить CRON с нужным окружением python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, crontab

система ubuntu
у меня есть вот такой скрипт test.py:

```
#!/home/my_project/venv/bin/python3.11
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/my_project/')

with open('text.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('ok')
```

он создает text.txt файл с текстом 'ok'

и без первых трех строчек он не работал, с ними все хорошо

я запускаю его при запуске сервера:

```
@reboot cd /home/my_project && /home/my_project/venv/bin/python3.11 test.py
```

и все отлично

но если я использую какие то сторонние библиотеки, которые изначально нету в окружении, а надо установить, например добавляю в скрипт

```
from requests import request
res = request(method='get', url="https://www.google.ru/")
print(res)
```

то  скрипт не запускается, мне кажется из-за того что он грузит не мое окружение, где был установлен pip install requests, а стандартное

но самое странное, что если запускать не при запуске сервера а каждую минуту

```
* * * * * cd /home/my_project && /home/my_project/venv/bin/python3.11 test.py
```

то скрипт отрабатывает даже с requests

как сделать так чтобы при перезапуске сервера, скрипт запускался с requests?

момент про 3.11:  что так python3.11 что так  python все работает одинаково

Answer (score 0):

сначала указываешь текущее окружение

```
env_name = "название текущего окружения"
```

потом добавляешь путь до virtualenv

```
activate_this = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".virtualenvs", env_name, "bin", "activate_this.py"))
sys.path.insert(0, activate_this)
```

Должно помочь, мне помогло во всяком случае

Comment: к сожалению  
activate_this = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".virtualenvs", "venv", "bin", "activate_this.py"))  
sys.path.insert(0, activate_this)   не помогло, но есть еще один момент у меня нет в папке bin файла activate_this.py а вписывание вместо него python3.11 тоже не помогло

Answer (score 0):

помогла задержка sleep 10; сервера после перезагрузки

```
@reboot sleep 10; cd /home/my_project && /home/my_project/venv/bin/python3.11 test.py
```

видать что то не успевало прогрузится